# Parsing strings with embedded multi line control character seuqences

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am writing a compiler for the realtime programming language PEARL.
PEARL supports strings with embedded control character sequence like this e.g.

```
'some text'\1B 1B 1B\'some more text'.
```

The control character sequence is prefixed with '\ and ends with \'.
Inside the control sequence are two digits numbers, which specify the control character.

In the above example the resulting string would be

```
'some textESCESCESCsome more text'
```

ESC stands for the non-printable ASCII escape character.

Furthermore inside the control char sequence are newline allowed to build multi line strings like e.g.

```
'some text'\1B 
1B 
1B\'some more text'.
```

which results in the same string as above.

```
grammar stringliteral;

tokens {
    CHAR,CHARS,CTRLCHARS,ESC,WHITESPACE,NEWLINE
}

stringLiteral:  '\'' CHARS? '\'' ;

fragment
CHARS: CHAR+ ;

fragment
CHAR: CTRLCHARS | ~['\n\r] ;

fragment
ESC: '\'\\' ;

fragment
CTRLCHARS: ESC ~['] ESC;

WHITESPACE: (' ' | '\t')+ -> channel(HIDDEN);

NEWLINE: ( '\r' '\n'? | '\n' ) -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

The lexer/parser above behaves very strangely, because it accepts only 
string in the form 'x' and ignores multiple characters and the control chars sequence.

Probably I am overseeing something obvious. Any hint or idea how to solves this issue is welcome!

I have now corrected the grammar according the hints from Mike:

```
grammar stringliteral;

tokens {
     STRING
}

stringLiteral: STRING;
STRING: '\'' ( '\'' '\\' | '\\' '\'' | . )*? '\'';
```

There is still a problem with the recognition of the end of the control char sequence:

The input 'A STRING'\CTRL\'' produces the errors

```
Line 1:10 token recognition error at: '\'
line 1:11 token recognition error at: 'C'
line 1:12 token recognition error at: 'T'
line 1:13 token recognition error at: 'R'
line 1:14 token recognition error at: 'L'
line 1:15 token recognition error at: '\'
```

Any idea? Btw: We are using antlr v 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with this grammar:

1. You cannot use a **fragment** lexer rule in a parser rule.
2. Your string rule is a parser rule, so it's subject to automatic whitespace removal you defined with your `WHITESPACE` and `NEWLINE` rules.
3. You have no rule to accept a control char sequence like `\1B 1B 1B`.

Especially the third point is a real problem, since you don't know where your control sequence ends (unless this was just a typo and you actually meant: `\1B \1B \1B`.

In any case, don't deal with escape sequences in your lexer (except the minimum handling required to make the rule work, i.e. handling of the `\'` sequence. You rule just needs to parse the entire text and you can figure out escape sequences in your semantic phase:

```
STRING: '\' ('\\' '\'' | . )*? '\'';
```

Note `*?` is the non-greedy operator to stop at the first closing quote char. Without that the lexer would continue to match all following (escaped and non-escaped) quote chars in the same string rule (greedy behavior). Additionally, the string rule is now a lexer rule, which is not affected by the whitespace skipping.

Comment: The control character sequence start indeed with '\ (apostrophe backslash) and ends with \' (backslash apostrophe).

Comment: OK, at least this part is clarified now. Still, I recommend to handle that after the normal parse run. It's easy to extract the embedded quoted part as control sequence and convert that for further use (e.g. in a listener).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. That what I am doing. The lexer rule StringLiteral contains the whole string with control chars and in the code generator I am taking it apart.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with this grammar snippet by adapting the approriate rules from the lates java grammar example:

```
StringLiteral
    :   '\'' StringCharacters? '\''
    ;

fragment
StringCharacters
    :   StringCharacter+
    ;

fragment
StringCharacter
    :   ~['\\\r\n]
    |   EscapeSequence
    ;

fragment
EscapeSequence
    : '\'\\' (HexEscape| ' ' | [\r\n])* '\\\''
    ;

fragment
HexEscape
    :  B4Digit B4Digit
    ;

fragment
B4Digit
    : '0' | '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '7' | '8' | '9' | 'A' | 'B' |     'C' | 'D' | 'E' | 'F'
    ;
```